# Lubuntu Openbox shortcut command not working

Tags: lubuntu, openbox

So I added the following command into my lubuntu-rc.xml document:

```
alias pbpaste='xclip -selection clipboard -o';vlc -vvv $(pbpaste)
```

and whenever I try to do the shortcut C-l-c, nothing happens.

Is there a specific way commands have to be done in this XML file to work?

This is my XML entry:

```
<keybind key="C-l-c">
      <action name="Execute">
        <command>alias pbpaste='xclip -selection clipboard -o;vlc -vvv $(pbpaste)</command>

      </action>
    </keybind>
```

Comment: • Please show us the exact part of your lubuntu-rc.xml. In other words, please post the relevant `<keybind> … </keybind>`. • Keep in mind that not all characters work in `<command> … </command>`. You may need to escape some characters: see [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=820355#p820355) for hints. • Sometimes, it maybe better to write a script and then assign a shortcut to that script. • BTW, what is `C-l-c`?

Comment: @DKBose This is my XML entry as it is right now

Comment: Did the answer I provided below work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me on Lubuntu 18.04:

```
<keybind key="C-W-C">        # my vlc
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>sh -c 'vlc -vvv "$(xclip -o)"'</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

Remember to run `openbox --reconfigure` after saving your edits to *lubuntu-rc.xml*.

If you have any output from `openbox --reconfigure`, you'll need to fix the issues mentioned.

---

Edit: You normally<sup>1</sup> can't have shortcuts with two non-modifier keys. Common modifier keys are <kbd>C</kbd> (for Control), <kbd>A</kbd> (for Alt), <kbd>S</kbd> (for Shift) and <kbd>W</kbd> (for Windows aka Super).

<sup>1</sup> See https://web.archive.org/web/20190815101235/http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings for more:

> Key combination
>
> KEY-COMBINATION is the key combination which you want to bind to the
>   actions. The format for the KEY-COMBINATION is: Modifier-Modifier-Key.
>   Any number of modifiers (0 or more) can be used together, and they are
>   each separated by a "-". Multiple KEY-COMBINATION can be specified in
>   one keybind by separating them with spaces. This is useful if you use
>   multiple keybinds for a thing that is quite complicated to specify.